# Link two PHP upload forms?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have created two separate PHP forms.. One to upload a video (so it accepts .avi, .mp4, .ogv), and then another to upload the video thumbnail (so it accepts .png, .jpeg). Is there any way I can link these so that they are created under the same name in their respective folders or anything? And can I make the video thumbnail form only show up after the video one has been submitted? Thanks.

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 220200960); //define a constant for the maximum upload size (200 MB)
if (array_key_exists('uploadvideo', $_POST)) {
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'videos/'); // define constant for upload folder
$file = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['video']['name']); //replace any spaces with underscores, and at the same time assign to a simpler variable
$max = number_format(MAX_FILE_SIZE/1048576, 210). 'MB'; //convert the maximum size to MB
$permitted = array('video/x-msvideo','video/mp4','application/ogg');
$sizeOK = false; //begin by assuming the file is unacceptable
$typeOK = false;
if ($_FILES['video']['size'] > 0 && $_FILES['video']['size'] <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
$sizeOK = true;
} //check that file is within the permitted size

foreach ($permitted as $type) {
  if ($type == $_FILES['video']['type']) {
    $typeOK = true;
    break;
    }
  }

if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
switch($_FILES['video']['error']) {
  case 0: //move the file to the upload folder and rename it
  $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$file);
  if ($success) {
    $result ="$file uploaded successfully";
    }
  else {
    $result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
    }
  break;
 case 3:
    $result = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
 default:
    $result = "Sysstem error uploading $file. Contact webmaster.";
 }
}
elseif ($_FILES['video']['error'] == 4) {
    $result = 'No file selected';
    }
else {
    $result = "$file cannot be uploaded. Maximum size: $max. Acceptable file types: .avi, .mp4, .ogv.";
    }
}
?>

<?php
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10485760); //define a constant for the maximum upload size (200 MB)
if (array_key_exists('uploadthumb', $_POST)) {
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'thumbs/'); // define constant for upload folder
$file = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['thumb']['name']); //replace any spaces with underscores, and at the same time assign to a simpler variable
$max = number_format(MAX_FILE_SIZE/1048576, 10). 'MB'; //convert the maximum size to MB
$permittedthumb = array('image/jpeg','image/pjpeg','image/png', 'image/x-png');
$sizeOK = false; //begin by assuming the file is unacceptable
$typeOK = false;
if ($_FILES['thumb']['size'] > 0 && $_FILES['thumb']['size'] <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
$sizeOK = true;
} //check that file is within the permitted size

foreach ($permittedthumb as $type) {
  if ($type == $_FILES['thumb']['type']) {
    $typeOK = true;
    break;
    }
  }

if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
switch($_FILES['thumb']['error']) {
  case 0: //move the file to the upload folder and rename it
  $successthumb = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$file);
  if ($successthumb) {
    $resultthumb ="$file uploaded successfully";
    }
  else {
    $resultthumb = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
    }
  break;
 case 3:
    $resultthumb = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
 default:
    $resultthumb = "Sysstem error uploading $file. Contact webmaster.";
 }
}
elseif ($_FILES['thumb']['error'] == 4) {
    $resultthumb = 'No file selected';
    }
else {
    $resultthumb = "$file cannot be uploaded. Maximum size: $max. Acceptable file types: .avi, .mp4, .ogv.";
    }
}
?>
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<h3 class="titlehdrblue">Upload Video</h3>
<br></br>
<?php
if (isset($result)) {
echo "<p><strong>$result</strong></p><br></br>";
  }
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadVideo" id="uploadVideo">
<p>
  <label for ="video">Upload video:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MAX_FILE_SIZE; ?>" />
  <input type="file" name="video" id="video" />
</p>
<br></br>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="uploadvideo" id="uploadvideo" value="Upload Video" />
</p>
</form>

<br></br>
<br></br>
<h3 class="titlehdrblue">Upload Video Thumbnail</h3>
<br></br>
<?php
if (isset($resultthumb)) {
echo "<p><strong>$resultthumb</strong></p><br></br>";
  }
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadThumb" id="uploadThumb">
<p>
  <label for ="thumb">Upload thumbnail:</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MAX_FILE_SIZE; ?>" />
  <input type="file" name="thumb" id="thumb" />
</p>
<br></br>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="uploadthumb" id="uploadthumb" value="Upload Thumbnail" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Give us your current code and (both HTML and PHP) and we'll help you combine them. Just saying what you want and what you have gives us no real idea what your problem is

Comment: Edit your question and add that code..

Answer (score 0):

Just put that thumbnail input in your video-upload form and you'll receive both at the same time